# What is the most effective way to read a file without any leaks in production app using java 7

Tags: java, inputstream, java-7, fileinputstream

I am using [this File leak detector](http://file-leak-detector.kohsuke.org) to figure out opened files in my production code. I have a website which uses below piece of code during query preparation process from a template file. This template file is closed only half the time, so in general left open FD's is a huge number.

```
public String getQuery(String templateName, Map<String, String> tmplMap) {
    String content="";
    try (InputStream istream = new FileInputStream(new File(templateName));) {
        content = IOUtils.toString(istream);

        // content = IOUtils.toString(UpgradeFeatureUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(templateName));
        for (String key : tmplMap.keySet())
            content=content.replaceAll(UpgradeConstants._PRE+key.toUpperCase()+UpgradeConstants._SUF, tmplMap.get(key));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return content; 
}
```

Template file content

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "default_field": "comp",
                    "query": "#%#COMP_ID#%#"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "query": {
                                "match": {
                                    "src_type": "#%#SOURCE#%#"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "query": {
                                "match": {
                                    "task_type": "#%#TASKS#%#"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 200
}
```

[File leak detector jar](http://file-leak-detector.kohsuke.org) throws an exception at

```
try (InputStream istream = new FileInputStream(new File(templateName));) {
```

statement, prior to this statement I was reading the template using `getResourceAsStream`, but later externalised the template file by putting it inside tomcat/bin/templates folder.

**Note:** I am using java 7.

**Update**

Exception by [File leak detector](http://file-leak-detector.kohsuke.org), which helps in identifying where/when/who opened files in your JVM.

```
Opened templates/featuretotask.template by thread:http-bio-19000-exec-8 on Wed Nov 30 22:19:34 IST 2016
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.xxx.UpgradeFeatureUtil.getQuery(UpgradeFeatureUtil.java:61)
```

Please let me know whether I need to close `FileInputStream` or `File` explicitly because I am already using try-with-resources Statement which ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement, so how is there a possibility of file discriptor left open?

Comment: what kind of exception?

Comment: what is the exception it throws? can you try with Files.readAllLines?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: I have added the exception given by File leak detector

Comment: You write in the question: "prior to this statement I was reading the template using getResourceAsStream". I don't understand if the template is in file system or classpath.

Comment: I think the "exception"  is no exception, but rather an information that a file is opened together with the according stack trace.

Comment: Are you sure that the posted code is the one that causes a file leak? try-with-resources should automatically close the resource.

Comment: Maybe you should start by not hiding potential problems (when reading your file) with `e.printStackTrace();` in your `catch` blocks, use `throw new RuntimeException("Error while reading template!", e)` instead. Or something the like.

Comment: @mm759: I ran File leak detector jar on my production app, then I left my app without using it, so that it becomes idle and then I counted total number of times this template was opened and closed (Log given by FLD jar). The stacktrace in that log points to the same statement I mentioned in my question. So yes the same line is causing file leak.

Comment: @Ricky: I am not 100% sure that `new File` does not open a file descriptor. You can test by moving it to a separate line.

Comment: @Ricky: One more idea: I guess it is possible that the same file is accessed multiple times at the same time. What if file descriptors are shared internally and File Leak Detector does not take this into account and prints misleading results. Do you have a second source of data that says that the number of open file descriptors rises?

Comment: @mm759: I need to look at other ways to figure out FD open as this might be misleading.

Comment: @mm759: Can you suggest any tool to figure out memory leaks in a java program?

Comment: @Ricky: Unfortunately, I don't know such a tool.

Comment: There is no leak in your try-with-resource. It looks to me that the file-leak agent does not correctly recognize close calls from a autoclose. (Or maybe the message "Opened" does not mean "leak").

Answer (score 0):

If you start distrusting the try-with-resource statement, there wouldn’t be any solution, as everything you do in the programming language requires trust in the correctness of the compiler generated code.

Still, you should minimize the duration you hold the resource:

```
public String getQuery(String templateName, Map<String, String> tmplMap) {
    String content;
    try(InputStream istream = new FileInputStream(templateName)) {
        content = IOUtils.toString(istream);
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(templateName+" does not exist");
    }
    for(String key: tmplMap.keySet())
        content=content.replaceAll(UpgradeConstants._PRE+key.toUpperCase()+UpgradeConstants._SUF, tmplMap.get(key));
    return content; 
}
```

Note that this leak detector *always* creates an exception as this is the way to record the stack trace of the opening place and at this point it is not known yet, whether the resource will be closed.

From the output shown in your question, it is not recognizable whether there is a leak or not. It doesn’t say so explicitly; all that is stated there is that it has been opened.

---

By the way, it’s an anti-pattern to iterate over the keys of a map and perform a lookup for every key. If you need both, the keys and values, iterate over the entries in the first place:

```
for(Map.Entry<String,String> e: tmplMap.entrySet())
    content=content.replaceAll(UpgradeConstants._PRE+e.getKey().toUpperCase()
                              +UpgradeConstants._SUF, e.getValue());
```